# epoll_wait() on a listener socket and spurious failures

Tags: sockets, listener, epoll

I'm seeing the following interaction between `epoll_wait()` and a listener socket.  The sequence of events for creating the listener socket is:

1. call `socket()`
2. call `bind()`
3. call `fcntl()` and set to non-blocking
4. call `epoll_ctl()` with `EPOLL_CTL_ADD` and `EPOLLET | EPOLLONESHOT | EPOLLIN`
5. call `listen()`

There are background threads calling `epoll_wait()` for this socket and others, and if one happens to do so between step 4 and 5 then an `EPOLLHUP` event is received for the listener socket.  Changing the sequence to:

1. call `socket()`
2. call `bind()`
3. call `fcntl()` and set to non-blocking
4. call `listen()`
5. call `epoll_ctl()` with `EPOLL_CTL_ADD` and `EPOLLET | EPOLLONESHOT | EPOLLIN`

resolves this problem, but now I see spurious failures where the connection is made but an `EPOLLIN` event is not received for the listener socket.

I understand one could alternatively use level-triggered mode, but I would like to get this working for edge-triggered mode.

Any thoughts on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of `EPOLLONESHOT` are that, once a notification has been pulled by `epoll_wait()` for some descriptor, you will have to call `epoll_ctl()` with `EPOLL_CTL_MOD` to *re-enable* notifications on that descriptor. So, you could be missing connections simply because the `EPOLLONESHOT` has disabled notifications on the passive/listening socket. (In general, `EPOLLONESHOT` should *not* be used except for special circumstances; it is not boilerplate or voodoo to be automatically added to one's code.)

Further, with non-blocking edge-triggered semantics, on notification that the listening socket is input-ready, `accept()` needs to be called in a loop until an `EAGAIN` error is reported.  Calling `accept()` only once could leave other connections in the queue, and furthermore, another edge-triggered `EPOLLIN` event will not occur until a brand new connection is added to that queue. (That is, assuming `EPOLLONESHOT` is not specified, or the descriptor is re-enabled every time before the next call to `epoll_wait()`.)

**ADDENDUM** Eliminating EPOLLONESHOT is certainly worth trying. Why do you need it anyway?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I should clarify that the scenario for this spurious failure is with the first and only connection made to the listener port.  So the listener descriptor has only ever been through an EPOLL_CTL_ADD, and EPOLLONESHOT hasn't come into the picture yet.

Comment: As an experiment, I changed from edge-triggered to level-triggered and still see the spurious failure.  Looking over recent linux kernel discussions, there appears to be a EPOLLONESHOT bug that may be responsible... http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=135708457812386&w=2

Comment: Have you tried a second connection, to see if this wakes the socket up and leads to two successful accept()s? That would indicate that edge-triggered notifications will not work if a connection is already in the listen queue at the point of EPOLL_CTL_ADD (unlikely, but you never know). You could get around this by calling accept() right away anyway (since it won't block). But, in general, edge-triggered semantics are not always a good idea for the read/input side.

Comment: As another experiment, I eliminated EPOLLONESHOT as well and still see the spurious failure.  This is quite puzzling.  In other code examples I've looked at, the listen() call is made after the listener descriptor is added to the epoll set.  But these examples don't have concurrent epoll_wait() calls.  I do, and had to move the listen() call ahead of adding the descriptor to the epoll set in order to avoid receiving an EPOLLHUP event.

Comment: I've never seen code where a socket is added to a poll set before being made passive via listen(). Even copies of man pages online, such as [this](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html), do the opposite. Do you have links?

Comment: It looks like you need to post a minimal "working" example. If others can't reproduce the problem on their systems with the code, that would indicate an environmental issue. Certainly an accept() detection failure with level-triggering (and no EPOLLONESHOT) is utterly bizarre, as epoll is the same as regular select and poll in that case.

Comment: I think there may be a thread-safe issue here.  Please see follow-on question 14238113.

Comment: Here's one example where listen() is called after epoll_ctl()... http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=125124776026132  I think it works because the example is single-threaded and the call to epoll_wait() occurs after the call to listen().  In any case, I'm calling listen() before epoll_ctl().

Comment: I found the problem and it actually has nothing to do with epoll.  My application is in C++, and thread pool creation involves a recursive template function with variable arguments and std::bind.  There is some strange sort of race condition occurring, where the resulting std::function object gets cleared and so the threads never enter the epoll_wait() loop.

Comment: This answer has a small error. Using edge trigger, the epoll will not wake when a new connection arrives. Until and unless an accept call returned with EAGAIN, it's as if the fd is not registered any more. The only sane use of ET is if a relevant call to epoll_wait will *always* be preceded by a call to read/accept/whatever. The only place I know that that's the case is when using micro-threads. Regular non-blocking mode should not use edge trigger.